# Appending to an array w/ its name passed as a bash function parameter

Tags: bash

I am writing a function that adds an element to the end of an array passed in parameter:

```
#@function add_elem_to_array: add an element to an array 
#in:
#1 name of the array
#2 element to add

add_elem_to_array()
{
   elem=$1  
   array=$2        
   index=${#array[@]} #get the index where to insert 

   eval "$array[$index]=$elem" #!!!! The problem is here
}
```

Could you please help me to figure out the solution?

Comment: Here's a page on dereferencing array elements in bash http://tldp.org/LDP/Bash-Beginners-Guide/html/sect_10_02.html

Comment: @GabrieleB-David thx, But in my case the name of the array is passed in param ; not the same case

Comment: Which version of bash? Do you have namevars?

Comment: Side note: your comment has the order of arguments mixed up.

Comment: BTW, using `${#array[@]}` to get the next index to write to is buggy. Arrays can be **sparse** in bash - meaning you can have an array `declare -a arr=( [15]=1 )`, having only one item, with that item's index being `15`, not `0`. `${#arr[@]}` won't give you the next index it's safe to insert at in such a case.

Comment: @chepner, the linked question appears to be about indirect array *expansion*, whereas this one is about indirect append operations. As such, I suspect there's probably a better duplicate to be found. (Feel free to notice me if you find it, and I'd be happy to re-dupehammer).

Comment: @CharlesDuffy There are a bunch about passing arrays by reference with solutions including using namerefs, but I can't see an *exact* duplicate.

Comment: @Mouin, ...btw, `eval "$array[\$index]=\$elem` is the smallest necessary change to the eval line to make it vulnerable only to malicious values of `$array`, not to malicious values of `$index` or `$elem`. Though you still have a bug in that `index=${#array[@]}` doesn't do what you think it does when your `array` variable is actually a string holding a variable name rather than an array itself; since the index isn't actually needed on any bash offering `+=` (which is ubiquitous these days), there's little need to dig into fixing that bug.

Comment: @Mouin, ...also, get in the habit of declaring your locals -- as it is, your function overwrites the global variables `elem`, `array` and `index` every time it's called.

Comment: @GabrieleB-David, please avoid linking TLDP as a reference -- their documentation is undermaintained and (particularly in the case of the ABS) has a tendancy to showcase bad practices. [BashFAQ #5](http://mywiki.wooledge.org/BashFAQ/005) is a more actively-maintained reference covering use of arrays in detail, whereas [BashFAQ #6](http://mywiki.wooledge.org/BashFAQ/006) is a comprehensive discussion of associative arrays and both indirect assignment and indirect lookup (being closer to what the OP is actually looking for here).

Comment: (I *do* remember back in the day when TLDP was a valuable resource, but that day was in the 1990s).

Comment: @CharlesDuffy Thanks for the tip. Will reference them in future

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Assuming bash 4.3 or newer, thus having namevars (`declare -n` / `local -n`):

```
add_elem_to_array() {
  local elem=$1 array_name=$2
  local -n array=$array_name
  array+=( "$elem" )
}
```

Supporting bash 3.x (particularly including 3.2, the oldest version in widespread use as of this writing):

```
add_elem_to_array() {
  local elem=$1 array_name=$2
  local cmd
  printf -v cmd '%q+=( %q )' "$array_name" "$elem"
  eval "$cmd"
}
```

---

That said -- given `array+=( "$value" )` as an available syntax, there's little need for a function for the purpose, is there?

Comment: Is that `eval` statement safe (from a code injection standpoint), or does it require the name, the value or both to be known safe?

Comment: @Fred, this one's entirely safe due to the use of `%q` on all substitutions. Content will be escaped so that it `eval`s back to its literal value, so if your name isn't a valid variable name you'll get a syntax error on that account, rather than arbitrary code execution.

Comment: @Fred [I provided an answer that does not require `eval`.](http://stackoverflow.com/a/41918519/6232717) I tend avoid eval like the plague out of habit.

Comment: @CharlesDuffy OK this solves the problem thank you for the references and the valuable infos

Answer (score 4):

I wouldn't use a function for this:

```
array+=("$elem")
```

appends an element.

If you really want to use a function and you have Bash 4.3 or newer, you can use a nameref:

```
add_elem_to_array () {
    local elem=$1
    local -n arr=$2
    arr+=("$elem")
}
```

Comment: Thank you it's quite as you said there is no need of function

Answer (score 2):

[Charles Duffy's answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/41914944/6232717) works perfectly for Bash 4.3+, but there's no simple solution if you're using an older version of Bash (unless you wish to trifle with `eval` for some awful reason). However, it can indeed be done!

### Here's what I whipped up:

```
## Arguments:
## $1 - the element to append
## $2 - the name of the array
append_to_array () {
    local -ia 'keys=(-1 "${!'$2'[@]}")';
    local IFS='';
    read -r -d '' -n ${#1} "$2"[${keys[${#keys[@]}-1]}+1] <<< "$1";
}
```

---

### Explanation:

Indirection can be tricky and took me forever to learn, but it's powerful and fun so I figured I'd explain how everything fits together.

Let's use `arr` as the name of an array.
When you append elements to an array with something like `arr+=(1)` or `arr+=("first element appended" "second element appended")`, the indices(keys) of the elements in the array simply increment by 1 for each element. For example:

```
$ declare -a arr=(A)
$ arr+=(B)
$ arr+=(C D)
$ declare -p arr
declare -a arr='([0]="A" [1]="B" [2]="C" [3]="D")'
$ echo ${#arr[@]}
4
```

You can see the size of the array is equal to the array's next available index, but this is not always the case. Continuing on:

```
$ arr[7648]="E"
$ arr+=(F)
$ echo ${#arr[@]}
6
$ declare -p arr
declare -a arr='([0]="A" [1]="B" [2]="C" [3]="D" [7648]="E" [7649]="F")'
```

**Line 1:**
This is why in the first line of my function, I create an integer array, `keys`, from the indices of `a` ( `${!arr[@]}` expands to the indices of `arr`. The last element in `keys` should be 1 less than the index we want to place the new element. However, if `arr` is unset or empty, `${!arr[@]}` will expand to nothing, so I put `-1` at the front of the `keys` to handle this.

**Line 2:**
Next up, we clear `IFS` (using `local` to avoid changing it outside of the function) to make sure any trailing or leading space characters in the appended element are preserved. Without clearing `IFS`, `read` and the here string operator `<<<` will strip leading and trailing space characters from `"$1"`, which is undesirable.

**Line 3:**
In the third line, we use `read` to copy the value from `"$1"` into the array referenced by `$2`. The `-r` prevents `read` from processing/interpreting special characters in `"$1"` and the `-d ''` option sets the delimiter to the null character to allow our elements to contain newlines (I will come back to the `-n ${#1}` option.).
`${#keys[@]}-1` evaluates to the index of the last element in `keys`, so `${keys[${#keys[@]}-1]}+1` grabs the last element of keys and adds one to it, forming our desired index to place `"$1"`.

The `read` command can be used to write to elements in arrays, e.g. `arr[2]="hi"` could be replaced with `read arr[2] <<< "hi"`, but `read` also works with indirect references to arrays, so we could also do `nam=arr; read ${nam}[2] <<< "hi"` or `i=2; nam=arr; read ${nam}[$i] <<< "hi"` and produce the same result. This is why `read -r -d '' -n ${#1} ${2}[${keys[${#keys[@]}-1]}+1] <<< "$1"` is able to append `"$1"` to the array referenced by `$2`.

Finally, `-n ${#1}` is required for reasons unknown to me. When I first wrote the script, every appended element had a newline character appended to it. I do not know why this is, so hopefully someone else can share some insight. So I just worked around this problem by limiting the number of characters read to the number of characters in `"$1"`.

Improved version that can append any number of elements and sanity-checks arguments:

```
## WARNING: THE ARGUMENTS ARE NOT IN THE SAME ORDER AS THE ABOVE FUNCTION
## $1 - the name of the array
## $2 - the first element to append
## $3-... - optional; can append any number of elements to the array
array_append () {
    [[ $# -gt 1 && $1 =~ ^[a-zA-Z_][a-zA-Z0-9_]*$ ]] || { 2>&1 echo "invalid args"; return 1; };
    local -ia 'k=(-1 "${!'$1'[@]}")';
    local n="$1" IFS='';
    local -i j=k[${#k[@]}-1] i=1 r=$#;
    while ((i<r)); do
        shift;
        read -r -d '' -n ${#1} "$n"[i+++j] <<< "$1";
    done;
}
```

Comment: To explain the need for the `-n` -- `<<<` implicitly appends a newline. `< <(printf '%s\0' "$1")` would avoid the issue, and cause `read -d ''` to correctly return success.

Comment: This *is* a good answer -- the only change I'd make is to quote more; by clearing IFS you're preventing string-splitting, but if a glob character made it into our arguments things could still get interesting. (It strikes me that quoting reflexively is something I do in the same manner in which you avoid `eval` -- because doing so as a consistently-applied habit avoids getting into sticky situations or showcasing practices that could be harmful if misapplied).

Comment: (not that `read` isn't returning success *now*, with `-n`, but when it was returning inaccurate results with an extra newline on the end, it was *also* exiting with a status of 1 since it wasn't finding the end-of-record delimiter it was being configured to look for).

Comment: @Charles Duffy Thanks for letting me know where that extra newline was coming from! Also, I have now updated the function to avoid any cases where a lack of quoting could cause an issue. Additionally, I added a function for appending and arbitrary number of elements.

Comment: At the risk of being pedantic -- `${#1}` still needs to be quoted to handle the case where IFS contains digits.

Comment: @CharlesDuffy By the time that line is reached, the IFS is guaranteed to not contain digits, as the function-scope IFS gets cleared a few lines prior

Comment: True. Still, you're providing code that's only correct *in context*, as opposed to code that's correct universally.

Answer (score 0):

Your problem is actually in the line where you determine the index.

```
   eval index=\${#${array}[@]} #get the index where to insert
```

You need to expand the variable containing the name of the array using the eval, *then* expand the expression to get its length. Escaping the first dollar sign inhibits the expansion of the array length request until after the eval.

The rest of the script appears to work as you intend.  Here is a debugging version that I used so show what is happening:

```
add_elem_to_array()
{
   elem=$1
   array=$2
   eval index=\${#${array}[@]} #get the index where to insert

   echo "elem ='$elem'"
   echo "array='$array'"
   echo "index='$index'"

   eval "$array[$index]=$elem" #!!!! The problem is here
}

arr=(This is a test)
echo "arr = '${arr[@]}'"
add_elem_to_array "one" arr
echo "arr = '${arr[@]}'"
add_elem_to_array "two" arr
echo "arr = '${arr[@]}'"
```

Comment: This does correctly fix the index determination, but it's not fixing injection vulnerabilities.